# Can't pass data between android activities in xamarin

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin

In all tutorial is this:

```
Intent newMainActivity = new Intent (this, typeof(Activity2));
newMainActivity.PutExtra ("MyData", hT);
StartActivity(newMainActivity);
```

But when i trying to do this, it still says "Android.App.Activity.Intent is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'"
The second and third line are ok, but the first doesnt work

```
Intent newMainActivity = new Intent (this, typeof(Activity2));
```

and error ;(

Comment: Your naming for the intent is very confusing. A better approach would be `mainActivityIntent` or something like that. That would make it easier to read and understand your code.

Answer (score 7):

[Android.App.Activity.Intent](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.Activity.Intent/) is a "Property" so the error is absolutely correct, but you should be using "[Android.Content.Intent](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.Intent/)".

Check your `using` section, do you have any `using static` statements? If so, try commenting them at and insure that you have a `Android.Content` in the using section:

**Using Example:**

```
using Android.Content;
```

**Code Example:**

```
var newMainActivity = new Intent (this, typeof(Activity2));
```

*if you have to fully qualify it due to namespace confusion with something you are doing with `Activity.Intent`, then:*

```
var newMainActivity = new Android.Content.Intent (this, typeof(Activity2));
```